# Move wordpress site from Linux to IIS 7

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

We've installed MySQL, and the site loads correctly at its home/root level (http://foo.com), however, any 'fictional' or rewritten subdirectories instantly 404.

I dont know if this is a module or an httphandler issue, but it seems something might not be mapped correctly.

Any suggestions? It's basically a vanilla install of PHP (although 'PHP Manager' has turned up in IIS).

Answer (score 3):

IIS does not support mod_rewrite so you can't have nice permalinks , you need to go into the admin and change you're permalink structure to default ( index.php?p=1234 ) .

---

Edit

Here is a link that explains how you can setup prety permalinks on IIS 7 asuming you have admin rights [Permalinks without mod_rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) ( search that page it has a section witch tells you exactly how to set it up )

Answer (score 1):

IIS 7 supports URL rewriting which is required for enabling pretty permalinks in WordPress. You just need to install IIS URL Rewrite module and then follow the instructions here: http://ruslany.net/2009/05/iis-7-url-rewrite-module-support-in-wordpress-28/